# OrientDB: IllegalStateException: Cannot begin a transaction while a hook is executing

Tags: orientdb

I'm getting this error when I try to insert 17000 vertex in the DB. The vertex are grouped as a multiple tree an the commit occur when a tree has bean fulled readed/stored. The first tree has 2300 vertex, the second has 5500 vertex and is in this point when it fail.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot begin a transaction while a hook is executing
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.begin(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2210)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.begin(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:2192)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.ensureTransaction(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:229)
at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph.commit(OrientTransactionalGraph.java:177)
at net.odbogm.SessionManager.commit(SessionManager.java:351)
at com.quiencotiza.utilities.SetupInicial.loadRubros(SetupInicial.java:180)
at com.quiencotiza.utilities.SetupInicial.initDatabase(SetupInicial.java:48)
at com.quiencotiza.utilities.SetupInicial.main(SetupInicial.java:41)
```

It's a single thread app. It load the database with the initials records.
I have upgraded to 2.2.4 but I get the same error.

Thanks
Marcelo

---

Well. I solve the problem. It seem is something related to the activateOnCurrentThread() but don't know why it happened. What means that exception? Why it is throwing?

Comment: It's hard to understand the issue only with this information. Can you post the code snippet that you are using?

Comment: Did you solve problem? I have this error too.

Comment: At that time the problem was solved but still don't know why. I could not trace the error correctly.

Comment: I was working in my Object to Graph Mapper and making a many changes.

Answer (score 0):

I know its an old topic, but maybe its will help someone,
Had the same problem, a lot threads with many queries and updates.
So I started to work with one thread (SingleThreadExecutor in Java) and solve it,
I guess there is a bug in the locks of hooks